# Route some websites through VPN to access US websites

Tags: vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I already have an IPsec VPN between two sites:

871W - Canada
2851 - US

I'd like to route some websites through the VPN to use the internet connection of the 2851.

Does anyone have sample configuration to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: It really depends on how many sites your talking about?

If it's only a few then set your default gateway in Canada via the normal ISP, then find the IP address of your 'selected sites' and route them using a static route via your VPN tunnel.

There will be some maintenance to keep it working, however it's fairly simple.